# How can i decompress my json data using gzip format in android?

Tags: android, gunzip

I want to decompress json data and store into string.I tried more but not working well.

I called my jsonparser class to my activity it raised an error when i run my application.

Here, is my `JSONParse.java`

```
public class JSONParse {
    static String res=null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais=null;
    GZIPInputStream gzis=null;
    BufferedReader in=null;
    String str="";
    String outstr="";
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            }


            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            res=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);


            bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(res.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            gzis=new GZIPInputStream(bais);
            reader=new InputStreamReader(gzis,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            outstr="";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                outstr+=line;
            }
            Log.e("outSTR",""+outstr);
            reader.close();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outstr;
    }

}
```

Here, is my error

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unknown format (magic number ef1f)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:109)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:88)
at comman.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:77)
```

Please, help me to solve out this error.

Comment: If you really get gzipped data then do not put that is a String first. Just let the gzip decoder use the input stream of the client.

Comment: `I want to decompress json data `. No you want to decompress compressed data.

Comment: Give me a code please.

Comment: `res=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);` Is that really compressed? Please Log.d() it and tell what you see. If the transfer is gzipped then your http client should automatically unzip it. If HttpClient is not doing that then use HttpUrlConnection.
`

Comment: https://www.cricketapi.com/docs/concepts/ read this link content and tell me what will i do?

Comment: Sorry i told you what YOU had to do already.